# Paypal Code error. Redirecting to error 400

Tags: php, html, css, paypal

Hello all i just need to make a simple page. And need to practice how we integrate paypall in our website and use it. But i don't what is the problem it redirect me to 400 error page. Here is my code.

```
<table class="right" >
          <?php

         while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="image-container"><img src="images/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>" class = "image"/></td>
            <td><h3 class="Product-Name">name: <?php echo $row['name'];?></h3> <h4>Price <?php echo $row['price']; ?></h4></td>
            <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_ext-enter">
            <form name = "subs" action = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="mona22-merchant@softgetix.com">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value = <?php echo $row['price'] ?> id="paypalamt">

                 <input type="hidden" name="item_name"  value = <?php echo $row['name']?> id = "name" >
              <input type="image" src="../images/mobile2.jpg" border="0" name = "submit">
            </form>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </table>
```

Comment: You're generating `id`s for your elements withing a loop, so you'll have multiple elements with the same `id`s which may not cause problems now, but may in the future. I suggest you solve this as soon as the current problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The inputs with ( name="amount" & name="item_name" ), thier values have to be enclosed like this :

```
value ="php code inside"
```

Comment: done sir, but same problem This is the message "We aren't able to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time. Please go back to the merchant and try using a different payment method."

Comment: I believe that you are using a wrong api or not defined values, as I can see you use the sandbox for paypal, which I greatly know you need to mark your account as Business and setup the api for sandbox and pass it hidden with your form.. sorry im not a paypal specialist, but if you use wordpress you have alot of great plugins to do the work so

Comment: you can easily use a button created by paypal itself to get payed.

Comment: sir, i did every thing make button from paypal website. But couldn't get any solution. can you please tell me any another solution for this. Any account setting or something else.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log in to your paypal account.
2. Go to Tools > Business Setup.
3. Scroll down to Paypal Buttons:

[image]

4. You have on the right side an option with : Create new button

[image]

5. Add and edit your button.

Comment: sir, not this error is gone. But now it can not accepting price. it accept name of item but not get price. I am using <input type="hidden" name="amount"  value="php code to get price from data base">

Comment: you need to change name="amount" to name="price" as paypal accept the form with price name not amount